# How to make a specific wavy plane

Tags: displacement, mathematics

I want to build a 2D Logo in 3D and it includes a wavy plane and I couldn't really get it to work.

The logo looks like this:[image]

And I want to make the Salad in 3D to look like this:
[image]

I tried using the wave modifier but it didn't really work out. Another try might be to use a Z Function Object but I didn't manage to find the function to this Picture.

I hope you can help me, stay safe, and have a great day ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Geometry nodes are the best solution because they are non-destructive and allow you to quickly change the result in real time.

[image]

Note that the wave corner on the reference should be pointing down.
[image]

Comment: True. A better way than mine.

Answer (score 6):

This can be a <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>  *Add > Mesh > Math Function Z Math Surface*, some variation of:

`z = sin(x) * cos(y)`. (Or for a phase-shift.. `z = sin(x) * sin(y)` etc.)

[image]

- Set the XY dimensions of your surface to some nice multiple of `pi/2`, maybe, depending on where you want your wave to intersect the boundaries
- Or shift the surface with respect to its boundaries by adding a some number to `x` and/or `y`..
- Don't worry about the height, you can always scale in Z, in Edit Mode, to change that.

The above version has *Solidify*, *Bevel*, and *Subdivision Surface* modifiers.. the *Solidify* has a material-index-shift to get the green rim.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by using geometry nodes.

(You can use the viewer node to see the changes visually)
I seperated the X-component of the position and passed it through a Math:Modulo to get a repetition. Then used a map range to keep it between one and zero. After that I put it through a color ramp to get a 0-1-0 pattern. Now I put his thorugh a Math: Sine to get a bit of smoothing.(You can use a RGB Curves instead and get the kind of smoothing you want instead)

Now I did the same thing with the Y-component and mixed the two using a Math: Minimum. Then I fed that into Combine XYZ: Z. Now using the set position node, I was able to displace it.

Change the value going into the node groups to change the number of zig-zags.
Change the multiplication value before the combine XYZ to controlthe height.

[image]

[image]

This is the final result:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

These are amazing and accurate answers but if ur looking for a simpler approach using wave modifier so check this out:[image]

Comment: The problem is that the curve on the border does not match the reference image, which makes such a solution useless.